# How to sort object array in ascending order based on instance variables using the following code

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

im trying to sort this object array without comparator or array list. sorting int the array for average score. here how it is used in the main method if someone could give me an idea that would be helpful i really dont want to use an array list or comparator, so i guess i need algorithm to help me, but im struggling figuring one out copy right reserved to Devan Underwood  :

```
public void calcAvgScore()
{
    avgScore = (test1 + test2) / 2;   
}
```

then in the constructor is:

```
 public Student(String newName, int newId, int newTest1, int newTest2)
{ 
    super(newName, newId);
    test1 = newTest1;
    test2 = newTest2;
    calcAvgScore();
    calcGrade();
}
```

Then:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Student[] score = new Student[5];

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter your students first name, id number, and two test scores");
    String newName = keyboard.next();
    int newId = keyboard.nextInt();
    int newTest1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    int newTest2 = keyboard.nextInt();

    Student student1 = new Student(newName, newId, newTest1, newTest2);

    System.out.println("Please enter your second students first, id number and two test scores");
    String newName2 = keyboard.next();
    int newId2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    int newTest12 = keyboard.nextInt();
    int newTest22= keyboard.nextInt();

    Student student2 = new Student(newName2, newId2, newTest12, newTest22);

    System.out.println("Please enter your third students first name, id number, and two test scores");
    String newName3 = keyboard.next();
    int newId3 = keyboard.nextInt();
    int newTest13 = keyboard.nextInt();
    int newTest23= keyboard.nextInt();

    Student student3 = new Student(newName3, newId3, newTest13, newTest23);

    System.out.println("Please enter your fourth students first name, id number, and two test scores");
    String newName4 = keyboard.next();
    int newId4 = keyboard.nextInt();
    int newTest14 = keyboard.nextInt();
    int newTest24= keyboard.nextInt();

    Student student4 = new Student(newName4, newId4, newTest14, newTest24);

    System.out.println("Please enter your fifth students first name, id number, and two test scores");
    String newName5 = keyboard.next();
    int newId5 = keyboard.nextInt();
    int newTest15 = keyboard.nextInt();
    int newTest25= keyboard.nextInt();

    Student student5 = new Student(newName5, newId5, newTest15, newTest25);

    score[0] = student1;
    score[1] = student2;
    score[2] = student3;
    score[3] = student4;
    score[4] = student5;
    System.out.println("____________");

     max = score[0];
    int i;
    for(i =0; i < score.length; i++)
    {

        System.out.println(score[i]);

        System.out.println("____________");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Not related to the question, but I would recommend you to write a function `Student createStudentFromUserInput()` which reads all the needed values, creates a new Student object and returns that – You will safe 25 lines in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply like this: you can sort without `Comparator`, instead you implement it yourself. In another word, actually you cannot. Algorithm cannot help you, as far as I see. If you don't have the average score, how you fill the array to sort?

1. Save the average grade in your `Student` class, as you did. (although I think you may have to change the constructor. It's better to provide the `Student` class's details.)
2. You sort with `student.avgScore`.

Like:

```
max = score[0];
int x = 0;
Student temp = null;
for (int i=0; i < score.length; i++) {
    x = score[i].avgScore;
    temp = score[i];
    if (x < score[i+1].avgScore ) {
        score[i] = score[i+1];
        score[i+1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Just a rough idea. Algorithm speeds up the sorting, but you sort with actual data.

Comment: i changed it to this to better fit my program to this                                         Student max = score[0];
        double x = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < score.length; i++) {
            x = score[i].avgScore;
            if (x < score[i+1].avgScore ) {
                score[i] = score[i+1];
                score[i+1] = x;
            }
        } and it says student cant be converted to a int i see why but idk how to fix it

Comment: I haven't run my code sorry. I have edited my answer. The key is we are swapping elements in an array, not a `double` with a `Student`. Are you coding with text editor instead of IDE like Eclipse? This kind of error should be detected by IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you pick up necessary sorting algorithm partition sort, merge sort etc. the key is that you have an array and you want to swap elements in the array for the sort to work. Given java is **pass by value** writing a method to which you pass array elements as score[i] and score[j] won't give you the required effect. 
Something like below won't have any effect for the caller

```
Student sArr[] = ...

swap(sArr[i], sArr[j])
```

You can however pass the reference to the array and indexes to be swapped, something as below

```
Student sArr[] = ...

swap(sArr, i, j);
```

Alternatively you can do all the swap in the same method where you implement your sorting logic no calling another swap method to move things around. hope this helps

To give you an idea of sort algorithm like shell sort with integers you'll do something as below (not the most efficient but to get you started)

```
// implement findMin and then do shellsort as below
public static void isort(int arr[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int mIndex = findMin(arr, i, arr.length);
        if (mIndex != i) {
            int temp = arr[mIndex];
            arr[mIndex] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Modify your logic to use comparison based on Student's average score in your case. You should also search on stackoverflow to get idea about sort algorithms. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Given the House class with the following information:-

```
Attributes:
houseType – char
price – double
area – double
owner – Person

Methods:
calculateTax()
toString()
Person class

Attributes:
name – String
ic – String
gender - char
government – boolean

Methods:
fromKelantan()
gender()
```

1. Write a default consructor and normal constructor for both classes
2. Write retriever and setter methods for both subclasses
3. Write processor methods for both subclasses

`Method calculateTax()` where it returns the tax for this type of land which depends on its area and the type of house build on the land as the table given below.

```
House Type Description Tax Rate(RM/m2)
T Terrace 10
S Semi-Detached 15
B Bungalow 20
C Condominium 30
```

`Method toString()` where it returns all the information.

`Method fromKelantan()` where it returns true/false depends on ic (Kelantan- 03) the table given below.

`Method gender()` where it returns ‘f’ or ‘m’ from ic.

Answer (score -1):

This looks you have array of student which you want to sort by avgScore but you don't want to use ArrayList or Comprator . If your sorting is based on abgscore then you can use any shorting Ex bobble . insersion , quick or  merge sort algo